# Trying to avoid a fact to fact relationship

Tags: domain-data-modelling

I am trying to avoid a fact to fact relationship but in this case it seems hard:

For several customers (DIM_Customer) we receive emails (FACT_email), Calls (FACT_CALL) etc. Now the emails and calls may have Surveys. Each Survey is unique for a Customer. As we know a survey consists of several questions.

So we have DIM_Survey (which basically is the survey type) and Dim_Questions And Fact_Survey (which contains the answers).

My question is how do I get the relationship between the email and the survey answers for that particular survey.